# Metro Styled Progress Bar in WPF

Tags: c#, devexpress, progress-bar, microsoft-metro

Is there any way to create a Windows 8 ProgressBar in WPF?

I don't mean the turning circle, I mean the one **animated** like that (with blue dots):

http://blog.humann.info/image.axd?picture=2012%2f3%2fanimated_loader.gif

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This control is implemented in the open source **[MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)** controls collection as the **MetroProgressBar** control.

Another - slightly different - loading control in this library that might interest you is the [ProgressRing](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#progress_ring).

Comment: You'll need to reference the whole MahApps.Metro project or dll to use the control. If you download the project in the MetroDemo project you can see examples on how to embed the progress bar.

Comment: For reference, it has been replaced by MetroProgressBar (Still in MahApps.Metro)